# Using $_POST to get select option value from HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

I use `select` as below:

```
<select name="taskOption">
    <option>First</option>
    <option>Second</option>
    <option>Third</option>
</select>
```

How do I get the value from the `select` option and store it into a variable for future use, in PHP?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Use this way:

```
$selectOption = $_POST['taskOption'];
```

But it is always better to give values to your `<option>` tags.

```
<select name="taskOption">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why is it always better to give values to your `<option>` tags? "[If no value attribute is included, the value defaults to the text contained inside the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)". If it works, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @osullic Agree, but I guess 5 years ago, a few browsers were not doing it.

Comment: Where do I put the $selectOption = $_POST['taskOption']; I put it in the php but it does nothing....

Comment: @YunfeiChen You have to put it on the page that the form is pointing to.

Comment: But now I only get the value (1,2,3) and not the text (First, Second, Third). What if I want both?

Comment: @Koko Stack Overflow has several pages which are fevoted to that topic.  Keep searching.

Comment: @Kokodoko `value="1-First"` you can give?

Comment: Thanks but my comment is already a year old :) I probably solved it!

Comment: @Kokodoko LoL yes... I didn't see it. But got a notification. How did you solve it though?

Answer (score 37):

You can access values in the `$_POST` array by their key. $_POST is an associative array, so to access `taskOption` you would use `$_POST['taskOption'];`.

Make sure to check if it exists in the $_POST array before proceeding though.

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
  <select name="taskOption">
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">Second</option>
    <option value="third">Third</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit the form"/>
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
   $option = isset($_POST['taskOption']) ? $_POST['taskOption'] : false;
   if ($option) {
      echo htmlentities($_POST['taskOption'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
   } else {
     echo "task option is required";
     exit; 
   }
```

Answer (score 17):

You can do it like this, too:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['select1'])){
    $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
    switch ($select1) {
        case 'value1':
            echo 'this is value1<br/>';
            break;
        case 'value2':
            echo 'value2<br/>';
            break;
        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
}
?>


<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="select1">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

for `php8+` versions, you can use `match` expression:

```
$select = $_POST['select1'] ?? '';

$result = match ($select) {
    'value1' => 'this is value1',
    'value2' => 'this is value2',
    default => 'unknown value',
};

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
<select name="taskOption">
      <option value="first">First</option>
      <option value="second">Second</option>
      <option value="third">Third</option>
</select>

$var = $_POST['taskOption'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on if the form that the select is contained in has the method set to "get" or "post".

If `<form method="get">` then the value of the select will be located in the super global array `$_GET['taskOption']`.

If `<form method="post">` then the value of the select will be located in the super global array `$_POST['taskOption']`.

To store it into a variable you would:

```
$option = $_POST['taskOption']
```

A good place for more information would be the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<?php
  $option = $_POST['taskOption'];
?>
```

The index of the `$_POST` array is always based on the value of the `name` attribute of any HTML input.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="taskOption">
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
<option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

try this

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['button_name'])){
$var = $_POST['taskOption']
if($var == "1"){
echo"your data here";
}
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**-- html file --**

```
<select name='city[]'> 
                <option name='Kabul' value="Kabul" > Kabul </option>
                <option name='Herat' value='Herat' selected="selected">             Herat </option>
                <option name='Mazar' value='Mazar'>Mazar </option>
</select>
```

**-- php file --**

```
$city = (isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city']: null);
print("city is: ".$city[0]);
```