# PHP get selected value from select box?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code for get database data to select box and i wanna get the seleceted value.I tries many ways but im missing something. help me

```
<form id="search" action="" method="post" >
   <select name="owner" id="owner">
   <?php 
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT designation FROM designation");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<option value="'.$row['designation'].'">'.$row['designation'].'</option>';
      }
      ?>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Try `<?php echo $_POST['owner']; ?>`

Comment: For future reference, you can do this to see all form data sent to the script: `print_r($_POST);`.

Comment: You have designation field in database table ?

Comment: where do you wish to select the value, at the back-end or at the front-end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using $\_POST to get select option value from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't specify an action for your form, the default will be to send the post values to the same page.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a) for more information about action value.

So, in the same page you have the form, you should add a

```
if(isset($_POST['owner']))
{
    // Do some stuff
}
else
{
    // Print the form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to include the action. Secondly to get a POST request of a select tag all you have to do is the following:

```
$_POST["owner"];
```

Comment: Action can be empty, there is no need to fill it. And what you mean by `POST request of a select tag`? Maybe `value of field sent using POST`?

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['owner']` contains the value of select box once you submit the form.And `$_POST` contains all the value of input elements you submitted via the form.if you `print_r($_POST);` it will show you all the values submitted through the form.

If you

```
echo $_POST['owner'];//Will display the value of your selected value in the select box.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="search" action="" method="post" >
            <select name="owner" id="owner">
            <?php 
             $owner="rejayi"
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT designation FROM designation");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
               if($row['designation'] ==  $owner){
     echo '<option value="'.$row['designation'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['designation'].'</option>';
               }else{
           echo '<option value="'.$row['designation'].'">'.$row['designation'].'</option>';
               }
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Double quotes (") outside and single quotes (') inside

eg:

`echo "<option value='".$row['designation']."'>".$row['designation']."</option>";`