# value not find in select option

Tags: javascript, php, post

I want, php find my value from select box but here don't find.

I have html:

```
<select name="outputFormat" id="outputFormat">
</select>
```

And js:

```
document.getElementById("outputFormat").options.length = 0;
var obj=document.getElementById("outputFormat");
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = "DOC";
opt.innerHTML = "DOC";
obj.appendChild(opt);
```

And my php is:

```
$outputFormat = $_POST['outputFormat'];
switch ($outputFormat) {
case 'DOC':
echo "find";  //here is not
break;
```

I see here, value is empty. What is wrong and how I fix this?
In the end my html look like this:

```
<select name="outputFormat" id="outputFormat">
<option value="DOC">DOC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Remove the colon in `echo:"find";` and change to `echo "find";` otherwise it will throw `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in...`

Comment: I trying to say, php say this is outputFormat empty

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still not work. Not go in this case.

Comment: Ask [Christoffer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25198266/) then, he put in an "answer".

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` to modify your options display value. The property for this manipulation is `textContent`.

Comment: I FIND PROBLEM: `document.getElementById("outputFormat").options.length = 0; ` here is problem

Comment: @NejcGalof Good, glad to know that. You can post it as your own answer and accept it when Stack let's you, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIND PROBLEM: `document.getElementById("outputFormat").options.length = 0;` 
here is problem

Answer (score 0):

Is your `<select>` placed inside `<form method="post" action="your.php">`? If you don't specify method, it will send the value in `$_GET` instead. You could check [Using $_POST to get select option value from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html) which is very similar.

Comment: Yes it is. If I write html it's works. If I create with js is problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean in your question..
maybe this seems like this case.
hope can fix your issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function addValue() {
    var obj=document.getElementById("outputFormat");
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = "DOC";
    opt.innerHTML = "DOC";
    obj.appendChild(opt);
}
//-->
</script>



<form method="POST" name="test">
<select name="outputFormat" id="outputFormat">
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="addValue();">
</form>
<?php
  $outputFormat = $_POST['outputFormat'];
  switch ($outputFormat) {
    case 'DOC':
    echo "find";  //here is not
    break;
  }
?>
```