# dropdown list of timestamp- retrieving image from database (query based on timestamp where clause)-php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

1.The Drop down list- lists the timestamp duration at which the images where put into database

2. To view a image, user selects the timestamp displayed in the drop down list and clicks submit
3. As soon as the submit button is pressed, "Connect.php" connects to database, makes "select" query comparing the timestamp in database to the timestamp user as selected

BUT I KEEP GETTING ERROR AS INVALID QUERY: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '19:21:43' at line 1

DATABASE TABLE HAS

1 "time_stamp" -datetime- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

2 "name" - varchar(200)

3 "images"- longblob

**kindly see the code and correct me**

**index.php**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("simpletest",$conn);
$qry= "select * from indu";
$result=mysql_query($qry,$conn);
$options="";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $options = $options."<option> $row[0] </option>";
}

?>
</head>

<body>
<form action="connect.php" method="post">
 <select name="selected">
 <?php echo $options; ?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php 
$connn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("simpletest",$connn);
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $v1=$_POST['selected'];
    echo $v1;
    echo "<br/>";
    $qrry= "select * from indu where 'time_stamp'=$v1";
    echo $qrry;
    $result1=mysql_query($qrry,$connn);
    echo $result1;
    if (!$result1) 
    { 
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
     }
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    echo '<img height"300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row1[1].'"/>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please do not write new code using the mysql functions. Learn PDO or mysqli.
I think the issue is that your query does not have quotes (') around the passed in time value.
`$qrry= "select * from indu where time_stamp='$v1'";` Although that might still not work if you are not also passing the date. Try and get a select statement working against your database and then change your code to emit that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have value in `<option value="">`. You need something like this:

```
 $options = $options."<option value=\"$row[0]\"> $row[0] </option>";
```

Comment: provided that am altering this to mine index.php, how could i knew in connect.php as what option has been submitted? what goes in $_POST[' ??' ]

Comment: here is example of usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html
you already useing name="selected" thus on another side you need to take selected from _POST

Comment: You don't have to pass a value, although it is recommended. If it is missing it will use the text between the <option> tags

Comment: That helped; am not able to query "select * from indu where time_stamp=$v1";

Comment: @AndyC ok, if that the case then the problem in quotes.

Comment: @induraj just check sample query directly with DB, that is fastest way to verify if it is working.

Comment: time_stamp in database has some value like this "2017-02-06 19:21:43" so while i query with
"select images from indu where time_stamp=2017-02-06 19:21:43" ...it doesnt query, should i convert the time_stamp into string and make comparison?

Comment: @induraj use what AndyC wrote in comment: $qrry= "select * from indu where time_stamp='$v1'";

Comment: perfect, its working fine, but the line -- echo '<img height="200" width="200" src="data:image;base64,'.$row1[0].'">';   produces lot of symbols that fills the entire page of the browser, and image icon appears without image!

Comment: @induraj that's another problem, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: Also in your original code you seem to be referencing the wrong column from the results. As I mentioned above, be aware that your code is open to sql injection attack and should not be used. Look in to prepared statements, mysqli and PDO

Comment: since am not using base64 encoding, i dont think i must mention base64 in the < img src "  ">..  tried using echo '<img height="200" width="200" src="'.$row1[2].'">';.. again the page full of symbols appears!

Comment: @laser   This worked Guys, Thanks for ur support--  echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row1['images'] ).'"/>';