# Get selected value from mysli_fetch_array and output

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to get a selected value and output it. Example i select **1001** from dropdown. When I echo it always return the value from first row wish is **1002**.

this my code **edit.php**

```
<form id="form" action="test.php" method="post">
    <?php
    echo "<select name=\"Reservation ID\" form=\"form\">";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $gg = $row['reserve_id'];
         echo "<option value='" . $gg . "' name=\"reserve_id\">" . $gg . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    $_SESSION['reserve'] = $gg;
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

this is code from **test.php**

```
$y = $_SESSION['reserve'];
if(isset($_POST['form']))
{
  echo $y;
}
```

[dropdown value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z87JN.png)

[List of reservation ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRjBx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html).

**EDIT**:

After loop execution `$gg` will point to the *last* value in the list (1002 in this case). I believe you are trying to access the value of the user-chosen `<option>` of the `<select>` which can be done by:

In **edit.php**:

```
<form id="form" action="test.php" method="post">
    <?php
        echo "<select name=\"Reservation_ID\" form=\"form\">";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $gg = $row['reserve_id'];
            echo "<option value='" . $gg . "' name=\"reserve_id\">" . $gg . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        $_SESSION['reserve'] = $gg;//this is not required to get <select> value, but may be relevant to what you are doing otherwise
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In **test.php**:

```
$y = $_SESSION[''];//this is not required to get <select> value, but may be relevant to what you are doing otherwise
if(isset($_POST['form']))
{
    echo $_POST['Reservation_ID'];
}
```

Comment: the <select name etc etc is not a query. It was <select></select> tag from html written in php.

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding of the question, I have reviewed and edited my answer.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you attempting to get the value of the `<option>`, selected in the form, in test.php?

Comment: the <option> tag will output all the reservation ID from the database. Based on the output user need to select one and submit. Eg: in dropdown have reservation id 1001 and 1002, user select 1001 and submit. The problem is when user choose 1001, in test.php in output 1002. Means it only takes reservation id from first row which is 1002.

Comment: Correct. I have added a code example for what I intended.

Comment: @Isaiah the name should be `Reservation_ID`

Comment: I seen what you were going for in the edit (`reserve_id`), but the `<option>` in the form had that element so to clarify I adjusted the `<select>` name (in the form and test.php) to Reservation_ID.