# How do i create a site that uses menus/radio buttons to extract data from MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, menu, dreamweaver, dropdown

I've managed to construct a webpage template that has all the elements for a home page but I want to use the data in my database to then submit to produce results coming out once submitted.

When I choose the menu (which has successfully come through from the database) when I click submit and have a second php page to make this submit work, I do not get any results from the database or at best showing what I have selected.

What code do I need to produce results on submit page that would hold all the data selected?

I really am a beginner at this and using PHP, HTML, and Dreamweaver as my builder.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to understand HTML form methods and how to access form data using PHP.

For getting the values of the select box you can go to this link.

[Get select box value using `$_POST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html)

Comment: [How to get value radio button in PHP?](https://www.formget.com/php-select-option-and-php-radio-button/)

Comment: I have that knowledge but how do I go about making it appear. I'm finding it won't appear when it comes to 'submitting' it it just ends up being a white page. I'm obviously able to connect to the database because i can make the select menu populate with database data but it won't submit and show hen it submits.