# Inserting data into MySQL from a dropdown

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to make a dropdown list that allows users to select a training program that matches their needs, so when they select it, the option will go into a table in the MySQL database.

This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="sessionreq.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
            <option name='eg1'>Example option</option>
            <option name='eg2'>Example option 2</option>
            <option name='eg3'>Example option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="delete">Request</button>
    <br>

</form>
```

What I need is an SQL query that will go with it, so when they select 'Example option 3', it will be entered into the database in a column called `method`. I should be inserted into `method` with the values (depending on their option in the dropdown). For example, if the user selected `Example option 2` it would be inserted into `method` with the values `Example option 2`.

How do I populate database tables/columns with dropdowns?

Comment: Where's your PHP and attempt and MySQL? We won't write it all for you.

Comment: your select won't get submitted to the server because it doesn't have a "name" attribute. It's the `<select>` that needs the "name" not the options. And the `<option>` tags need "value" attributes with the values in that you want to be saved in the DB. Is that the issue? You've written the question as if you have no idea how to deal with PHP postbacks and database queries, but it's not clear. If that's the case, you should try some tutorials, because that's far too big a topic for a single SO question.

Comment: add `name="exampleSelect1"` attribute to select and use it in sessionreq.php file like : `$_POST['exampleSelect1'] `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all give name to your `select`. In this case I have given `training`

```
<form action="sessionreq.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="training">
            <option value='Example 1'>Example option 1</option>
            <option value='Example 2'>Example option 2</option>
            <option value='Example 3'>Example option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="delete">Request</button>
    <br>

</form>
```

Now in your `sessionreq.php` you can fetch the value through `$_POST` like

```
$_POST['training']; //You can manipulate the data anyway you like.
```

Now you can run the query to insert. Given is a prepared statement (prefered)

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['training']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: you probably need to add values to the <option>s

Comment: @MitchMewett `?` is a placeholder used in prepared statements. to protect against sql injections read more about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @MitchMewett the value of `$_POST['training']` goes into the ? when the statement is executed (because of the bind_param command). You can have as many ?s as you like in your query, and then you run bind_param the same number of times, passing each separate parameter you want to use to match the relevant ? (in sequential order). This is known as parameter binding and is much safer that just joining strings together - it's a key measure to protect your data against SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @Ali this form will not post the values to the db

Comment: I want to post the values into the database depending on the user selection... Like I said in the question, if they select 'Example 1', I want 'Example 1' to be in the `method` column. If this answer cannot achieve that, it's completely irrelevant to my question

Comment: OMG! I didn't see... @MitchMewett you have invalid HTML. Please check new HTML. In `option` element you have to give value. se

Comment: Solved, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html