# Can't get user input in PHP switch case from a dropdown menu

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm using ajax to take user input in a dropdown menu (so the input would be the chosen alternative) and show some information after a button is clicked. It works, but I want to use a switch case statement in the controller, which is not working.

I have this piece of code to populate the dropdown menu:

```
<form method="post" action="controleur.php">
 <select name="liste_formations" id="liste_formations" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Choisissez une formation</option>
  <?php 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo '<option value="'.$row["idActivite"].'">'.$row["nom"].'</option>';
  }
  ?>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
 <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn" id="search" value="Voir informations" />
</form>
```

And when the user clicks the send button it goes to controller.php where I have:

```
case "Voir informations":
             $idActivite = $_POST['liste_formations'];
             $query = "SELECT * FROM formation WHERE idActivite = '$idActivite'";
             $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
             {
              $data["nombreMaxPart"] = $row["nombreMaxPart"];
              $data["idFormateur"] = $row["idFormateur"];
              $data["prix"] = $row["prix"];
              $data["description"] = $row["description"];
             }

             echo json_encode($data);
        break;
```

When I try to do that I get the information I want, but in a blank page with the information vector. I actually want to show it in a table.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["idActivite"]))` is simply check if the given param exists and non null or empty.. if true then the code runs else the other code works.

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html/17139538

Comment: in controller.php, put the follow at the top of the page, submit the form and paste the results: echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';

Comment: I tried this echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';  thing and I got Array
(
    [liste_formations] => 64
    [action] => Voir informations
)